# Show loading image when Chart is loading

Tags: javascript, charts

I am using a CanvasJs chart. The chart is working fine. The Chart is taking time to load. I wanted to show a loading image until the chart loads. CanvasJs charts have no defined attributes for this. Any help is appreciated.

Html:

JS: 
chart = CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {});

Comment: Have you tried loading an image using the default canvas API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images

Answer (score 2):

You can add loader-image(gif) or some text within the chart-container div so that image/text is shown in the div till the chart is initialized.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 title: {
   text: "Basic Column Chart"
  },
 data: [
 {
  type: "column",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 10, y: 71 },
   { x: 20, y: 55 },
   { x: 30, y: 50 },
   { x: 40, y: 65 },
   { x: 50, y: 95 },
   { x: 60, y: 68 },
   { x: 70, y: 28 },
   { x: 80, y: 34 },
   { x: 90, y: 14 }
  ]
 }     
 ]
});

chart.render();
},2000);
```

```css
img{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 250px; width: 100%;">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fXUIBfi.gif" alt="Chart will Render Here..."/>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be marked as a correct answer. Works perfectly.